# List of data from matplotlib variables

Tags: database, python-2.7, datalist

I have two variables used in matplotlib, one of them has measured data, and a second one is a time scale from 0 to 300 s. What I need to do is to make a vertical list of them (both together, next to each other), to see in what time a certain measurement took place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use zip ([Doku](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)). The shorter of both list wins, the items of the longer one that do not match get discarded:

```
l1 = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
l2 = ["a","aa","aaa","aaaa","aaaa","discard","discard2"]

l3 = zip(l1,l2) # relates same indexes in bot lists as tuple (l1[i],l2[i]) 

for tup in l3:
    print(tup[0], "  " , tup[1])
```

output:

```
1    a
2    aa
3    aaa
4    aaaa
5    aaaa
```

The "vertical list" could already be what I called `l3` here - its a list of 2-tuples containing (in your case: `(time, value)` )

Save to file:

```
with open("demodata.txt","w") as f: 
    for tup in l3:
        f.write(tup[0], "  " , tup[1],"\n")
```

Comment: We are almost done, but after using that I have something like this:
`(array([  5.74434295e-02,   5.85697712e-02,   5.96961130e-02, ...,
         2.99981979e+02,   2.99983105e+02,   2.99984231e+02]), ' ', array([ 100.,  100.,  100., ...,  100.,  100.,  100.]))`

And first, that is not a full list, but some first and last measurements. Second they are printed in two lines instead of columns. Any idea? Still thanks for a good clue.

Comment: @Hiddenguy numpy arrays? Zip seems to zip two 1-element lists() that contains each 1 element of type array ....

Comment: Well that was my output. My input is 

`l1 = [cutoff1]
l2 = [BxTime]

l3 = zip(l2,l1)
for tup in l3:
    print (tup[0], " " , tup[1])`

Comment: remove the [] around the cutoff and BxTime - they are already lists - you put a list inside another list

Comment: Ahhh... You are right, you have solved my case, can you tell me also how to save it to a file, to see this list?

Comment: @Hiddenguy modified code, use \r\n on windows instead of \n if your editor is not smart enough to handle unix style lineendings